# Which design pattern helps me in this case using - Laravel

Tags: laravel, oop

so I have a controller which returns a view with a DB Collection which I have a repository,

now, in case I have a request I want to return an array - json and not a view

any ideas if this is the correct approach?

```
    public function index(
    Request $request,
    CampaignPerformanceRepository $campaignPerformanceRepository
) {
    $data = $campaignPerformanceRepository->getDataByPeriod($request);

    if ($request->all()) {
        return $campaignPerformanceRepository->getDataByPeriod($request);
    }

    return view('reports.campaign-performances', compact('data'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do something similar in cases where I may want to return a view or just json based on the request. There's an easy helper function request()->wantsJson() which you can use.

```
$data = $campaignPerformanceRepository->getDataByPeriod($request);

if ($request->wantsJson()) {
    return $campaignPerformanceRepository->getDataByPeriod($request);
}

return view('reports.campaign-performances', compact('data'));
```